# How to make a dolly effect?

Tags: video, after-effects, video-production

I was watching vertigo last night which is directed by alfared hitchcock and I saw some scenes in which he used 'dolly effect' I was wondering how do you make that effect?

Comment: Google for "vertigo effect" or "dolly zoom".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply explain it to you.you just go near or far from your subject but maintain your frame same by zooming out or in (by changing focal length) so in this way you get background compression or expansion and when you combine all these pictures just like you do in hyperlapse. Hope you got it...

Answer (score 2):

The "Vertigo effect" is achieved by zooming in while tracking out, or zooming out while tracking in. When done right the size of the subject stays the same in frame, while the perspective shifts unnaturally, giving an uncanny feel to the footage.

The effect is achieved in-camera. It could be replicated in post by separating the planes of the image along the depth axis and replicating the real-world camera movement, but it would be highly labour intensive, compared to doing it on set.

P.S. Just to be suuuper pedantic, a "dolly" is a sideways movement, a movement forward or backward is a "track".